# Can I spoof a specific AP of a network?

Tags: network, wifi, android, spoofing

My college wifi requires a certificate installation and also is very unreliable. Therefore, I prefer using my mobile data when I am on campus. But the college has its own app for attendance taking and the app requires a connection to campus wifi (SSID:eduroam) to take attendance. I have to manually connect to college wifi every time I want to mark my attendance (the process involves a single tap with a one-time authentication after installation).

So, out of curiosity, I was just trying to see whether I can trick it into thinking I am connected to the campus wifi. So, I tried creating a hotspot with the same ssid using another device and it seems the app doesn't return the same error when I try to mark my attendance using my mobile data. Now, it is displaying a different error along the lines of "device not in the room". My first thought is I have to be connected to specific campus AP because the app does specify the location at the side of each class. After some testing, I found out that the error in question is similar when I try to mark my attendance from a different location (hence different AP) when I am connected to the campus wifi.

Is it possible to spoof a specific AP and how would I go about doing it? Is it possible to do it on an android device?

Comment: You have an X/Y problem. You are assuming that the app looks for the AP. It likely needs to connect to the resources provided by the eduroam network. I work with eduroam applications and this is the typical set up.

Comment: Probably it is, but no-one here will help you to circumvent this arrangement. It's clearly there to prevent you from marking your attendance from home in your pajamas. You can use your own AP for accessing the Internet even without spoofing anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to spoof a specific AP and how would I go about doing it? Is it possible to do it on an android device?

Possibly, but pointless. Why?

> Now, it is displaying a different error along the lines of "device not in the room". My first thought is I have to be connected to specific campus AP because the app does specify the location at the side of each class. After some testing, I found out that the error in question is similar when I try to mark my attendance from a different location (hence different AP) when I am connected to the campus wifi.

This most likely indicates that your college is using an enterprise WLAN solution with location services. The attendance application is tied into the location data the WLAN solution is providing. Specifically, it is using the location data for clients connected to their wireless (while the locations services can track non-clients, client data is more accurate making this a relatively safe assumption). This makes a certain amount of sense as the college would not want students to log in from anywhere [not the classroom] to mark themselves present.

As such, no amount of "trickery" on your part will fool the college WLAN that you are an associated client when you are not.